# React: правильно распарсить массив в объекте

Tags: парсер, reactjs, объекты

Добрый день, есть объект и в нем еще 1 массив с данными, выходит примерно так:

```
{
    name: "Material"
    tagsName: [0: "ikea", 1: "Street furniture", 2: "restoration hardware"]
}
```

Подскажите как правильно распарсить tagsName что-бы можно было вытянуть каждый тег по отдельности?
Мой вариант, но вытягивает все теги в одну строку:

```
                {[this.state.funnelData].map((funnel, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={index}>
                            // name: "Material"
                            <span>{funnel.name}:</span>

                            //tagsName: [0: "ikea", 1: "Street furniture", 2: "restoration hardware"]
                            {[funnel.tagsName].map((value, ind) => {
                                return (
                                    <span key={ind}>{value}</span>
                                )
                            })}
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
```

Получается сейчас такое (надо что-бы каждый тег записывало в отдельный `<span>`):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 {[this.state.funnelData].map((funnel, index) => {
                return (
                    <div key={index}>
                        // name: "Material"
                        <span>{funnel.name}:</span>

                        //tagsName: [0: "ikea", 1: "Street furniture", 2: "restoration hardware"]
                        {funnel.tagsName.map((value, ind) => {
                            return (
                                <span key={ind}>{value}</span>
                            )
                        })}
                    </div>
                )
            })}
```

Не нужно оборачивать tagsName в массив - он и так уже массив

Comment: Пробовал так, пишет: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: Все верно, просто у меня данные не успевали приходить и выдавало tagsName undefined, пришлось условие на проверку дописать) Спасибо!